# How to do group by only date (not DateTime) for different time zones

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a collection that stores all the orders by date. The order date is stored in the database as UTC DateTime.

e.g. when I am sending a request from `EST` (just as a sample), and want to check the daily statistics of orders from `14/09/2022` to the end of `16/09/2022`, it comes to the server like `14/09/2022 04:00:00` to `17:09/2022 04:00:00`.

Now if I get the data from the database and group it based on the Date I will have the result for `14,15,16,17`. Since it was based on the date, the time will be `00:00:00`. And for the user who wants to see this data, it won't be correct because, in the report, the next day contains statistics for 4 hours of the previous day.

My database is MongoDB and I am doing this in C#.

My question is What is the best way to do the GroupBy Date based on the user's time zone?

One solution can be to get the data based on the start and end date time and do the grouping manually in a while loop.
But What is the other way to do this using LINQ GroupBy or on db side?

Comment: Dates are transferred between machine as number (DateTime) so best way is to use local time plus timezone (Add 4 Hours or 5 hours standard time).  Also use DateProperty.  So use following orders.Group(x => x.Date.AddHours(4).Date)

Comment: Have a look at [$dateTrunc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/), there you can provide also the time zone.